# Dynamic masked input according to data

Tags: javascript, regex, maskedinput

I have a response and it returns "XXX-XXX" or "XX-XXXX"

```
const formatUnitCode = (value, format) => {}
```

So basically, I want to see as `formatUnitCode("123456", "XX-XXX") --> "12-3456"`

I don't want to use if else because it may come in the future as XX-XX-XX

Can someone help me create this function?

I tried to do with regex but I think it is not possible to pass variable instead of {2} and {4}

```
const formatCode = (val) => val.replace(/(\d{2})(\d{4})/g, "$1-$2");
```

Comment: It would be polite to upvote or in the very least acknowledge answers, particularly if they solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you would like to do?

```
const func = (val, first_digit) => {
    let regex = new RegExp("(\\d{" + first_digit + "})(\\d{" + (6-first_digit) + "})","g");
    return val.replace(regex,"$1-$2");
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use variables in RegExp literals, but you can when you use the RegExp() constructor to build the pattern as a string instead.

```
const formatStr = (val, format) => {
  let ptn = format.split('-').map(part => '(.{'+part.length+'})').join('');
      match = val.match(new RegExp(ptn));
  match && console.log(match.slice(1).join('-'));
};
```

It's instructive to `console.log()` the `ptn` var to see what's happening there. We're using your arbitrary "X"-based format to derive a new, dynamic RegExp which will be used in a multi-match RegExp to grab the parts.

```
formatStr('123456', 'xxx-xxx'); //"123-456"
formatStr('123456', 'xx-xxxx'); //"12-3456"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple for loop make a dynamic string format method.

```js
const formatUnitCode = (str, format) => {
  let result = '';
  let j = 0;
  for (let i = 0, l = format.length; i < l; i += 1) {
    if (format[i] === 'X') {
      result += str[j];
      j += 1;
    } else result += format[i];
  }
  for (; j < str.length; j += 1) result += str[j];
  return result;
};

console.log(formatUnitCode('123456', 'XX-XXX'));
console.log(formatUnitCode('123456', 'XXX-XXX'));
console.log(formatUnitCode('123456', 'XX-XXXX'));
console.log(formatUnitCode('123456', 'XX-XX-XX'));
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for any mask regardless of the letters used (you can control that behaviour by changing matcher regex). Personally, I think it's a more elastic approach than just trying to match the given mask with a regex.

```js
const replaceWithFiller = (filler, str, matcher = /[a-zA-z]/g) => {
  const arr = filler.split('');
  return  str.replace(matcher, () => arr.shift());
};


console.log(replaceWithFiller('123456', 'XXX-XXX')); //"123-456"
console.log(replaceWithFiller('123456', 'XX-XX-XX')); // "12-34-56"
console.log(replaceWithFiller('123456', 'XX-XXXX')); //"12-3456"
console.log(replaceWithFiller('123456', 'aa-aaaa')); // also "12-3456"
```

Answer (score 0):

you can pass parameters to your regex using template literals:

```js
const formatCode = (val, format) => {
  const lengthFirstBlock = format.indexOf('-');
  const lehgthSecondBlock = format.length - format.indexOf('-');
  const regex = new RegExp(`(\\d{${lengthFirstBlock}})(\\d{${lehgthSecondBlock}})`, 'g');
  return val.replace(regex, "$1-$2");
} 

console.log(formatCode("123456", "XX-XXX"))
console.log(formatCode("123456", "XXX-XX"))
```